# retrieving and loading json from javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

My problem is really weird. I'm working in phonegap.

I got a function called "krijgSpellen". I call that function when "device ready" like so:

```
// Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        readFile();

        var options = { frequency: 3000 };
        watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);

        krijgSpellen(); <--



    }
```

but here is the weird part, when I do this:

```
function krijgSpellen(){


            $.getJSON("gegevens.txt",function(result){

// Get all the games
$.each(result.games, function(){
    $(".gamelijst").append("<li><a href='' id=" + this.id + " data-theme='a'>"+ this.game + "</a></li>");


                });

            $(".gamelijst, $.mobile.activePage").listview('refresh');


                      });   
};
```

That works, but when I do this:

```
function krijgSpellen(){


        $.each(jsonopgehaald.games, function(){
               $(".gamelijst").append("<li><a href='' id=" + this.id + " data-theme='a'>" + this.name + "</a></li>");
               });

        $(".gamelijst, $.mobile.activePage").listview('refresh');

    };
```

It doesn't work, and I have the same code on an hyperlink and when I click the hyperlink it does work. And I really need the method where it doesn't work to do it.

By the way

```
jsonopgehaald = {"games":[{"id":"2","name":"bartje","photo":"photo2.png","description":"kimpe","length":"is","totalDownloads":"0","totalFinished":"0","locations":[{"id":"3","name":"loc21","photo":"loc21.jpg","description":"loc21","FK_Game_id":"2","lat":"51.0000","long":"4.0000","status":"0"},{"id":"5","name":"loc22","photo":"loc22.jog","description":"locatie 22","FK_Game_id":"2","lat":"51.2330","long":"40.2222","status":"1"}]},{"id":"3","name":"aa","photo":"photo3.jPg","description":"aa","length":"aa","totalDownloads":"0","totalFinished":"3","locations":[{"id":"4","name":"loc4","photo":"loc4.jpg","description":"loc4","FK_Game_id":"3","lat":"51.2191","long":"4.4021","status":"0"}]}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function krijgSpellen(){

    $.each(jsonopgehaald.games, function(index, value){
           $(".gamelijst").append("<li><a href='' id=" + value.id + " data-theme='a'>" + value.name + "</a></li>");
    });

    $(".gamelijst, $.mobile.activePage").listview('refresh');

};
```

I tested it and it works. Added the `index` and `value` to function().
`value` is a reference to the array you are currently in.